# Submenu causes Nav Panel to disappear

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using a vuetify navigation drawer.  Inside is a submenu. When I expand/collapse the submenu it causes the navigation panel to disappear.  I am looking for the correct way to prevent that from happening.

I have an example here:
https://codepen.io/uglyhobbitfeet/pen/MWeBLwJ?editors=1010

Note - I purposely set the navigation panel to be temporary instead of permanent, because I don't want the menu displaying unless someone clicks on the hamburger icon.

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" absolute right temporary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation drawer disappear because your watch the property "group". So when group is toggled, the watcher see a change, and it update to false your navigation drawer, as you code it

As your submenu is a nested component, you don't need to add the v-model `group` just remove it and the watcher